# Prove that $3^{4^{5}} + 4^{5^{6}}$ is the product of two integers greater than $10^{2002}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $3^{4^{5}} + 4^{5^{6}}$ is the product of two integers greater than $10^{2002}$.

A friend already gave me a solution:
[image]

But I don't really see the motivation behind that. Can somebody tell me how I can note things like that when solving the problems?

Comment: Not an answer, but the factorization of $x^4+4^k$ as $(x^2-2^k x+2^k)(x^2+2^k x+2^k)$ is a contest golden oldie.

Comment: Thanks, do you know a site that contains more of this useful factorizations or ideas?

Comment: No, not really. There are good problems sites such as the Art of Problem solving but factorizations would be a tiny part of the content.

Comment: Also, there is a solution more close to the famous Sophie-Germain identity, which is setting the number to $m^4+4n^4$, where $n=2^{\frac{5^6-1}{2}}$. Then we actually directly apply the Sophie-Germain identity to factor. The motivation would probably then be that after finding no other solutions, we look for factorizations. The $4$ exponent in the problem might help in identifying it.